# T32 CMM Script from ARM DS

Tags: fpga, keil, trace32, lauterbach

I have a FPGA based system & ulink pro debugger with ARM DS IDE. I am able to connect and debug it.
I want to create T32 script for this. I know ARM DS accepts and can work with CMM scripts. Wanted to know if in anyway I can generate trace32 script from ARM DS?

Otherwise, can any one explain on how I can create one by taking input from working ARM DS model ?

Comment: Are you sure that "ARM DS accepts and can work with CMM scripts" ?  CMM scripts are usually interpreted by TRACE32 from Lauterbach. While TRACE32 can deal with the ELF (or AXF) files produced by the ARM DS compiler, I doubt that you can use CMM scripts with a ULINKpro debugger from Arm KEIL.

Comment: I believe so.. https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100953/0528/debugging-with-scripts/support-for-importing-and-translating-cmm-scripts/importing-and-translating-a-cmm-script